# Batch script to acquire all users list of local machine

Tags: batch-file, automation

Batch script to find all users having account in local machine except currently logged in user and other default users.

Code :

```
@echo off
SET "Value="
SET Users="dir C:\Users\ /B"
FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%A IN ('%Users%') DO (
    SET "Name=%%A"
    IF /I "%NAME%" NEQ "Administrator" (
        IF /I "%NAME%" NEQ "Public"(
            IF /I "%NAME%" NEQ %USERNAME% (
                SET "Value=%Value% "
                SET "Value=%Value%%%A"

            )
        )
    )
)
echo %Value%
```

Is this logic correct ? Having issue with syntax. Open to suggestions.
And i want to store all users in a single variable.

I think the above script when corrected will o/p like this :
`user1 user2...`

But i want to use newline function instead of space as delimiter. Something like :

```
user1
user2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SET "Value="
SET Users="dir C:\Users\ /B"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%A IN ('%Users%') DO (
    SET "Name=%%A"
    IF /I "!NAME!" NEQ "Administrator" (
        IF /I "!NAME!" NEQ "Public" (
            IF /I "!NAME!" NEQ !USERNAME! (
                SET "Value=!Value! "
                SET "Value=!Value!%%A"

            )
        )
    )
)
echo %Value%
```

You need [delayed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx) expansion and you've missed one space before one of the opening brackets.

Comment: Ahh, thank you... that worked. Also forgot to use double quotes on `!USERNAME!`

Btw regarding my second query, any way to store them line by line instead of space ?

Answer (score 0):

Small corrections:
Obtain user folder name, it works on winXP or later.
Added "" for spaces on User folder (ie:"Documents and Settings").
Delims=\ to obtain user dir names with spaces.
DIR /ad-h options to list only dirs in USERS folder, and make sure hidden dirs are not shown (-h)
%USERNAME% needed surrounding "":

```
@echo off
SET "Value="
FOR %%i IN ("%USERPROFILE%") DO set USERSDIR=%%~di%%~pi
FOR /F "Delims=\" %%A IN ('dir /ad-h "%USERSDIR%" /B') DO (
  IF /I "%%A" NEQ "Administrator" (
    IF /I "%%A" NEQ "Public" (
      IF /I "%%A" NEQ "%USERNAME%" (
        SET Value=!Value! "%%A"
      )
    )
  )
)
echo Value=%Value%
```